# Google scripts converting text parameter to acceptable date object

Tags: google-apps-script

I have scoured SO and the interwebs and discovered the horror that is date handling in Google Apps Script. I have found conflicting answers about date() and formatDate(), and have yet to find a definitive, working guide that shows the exact steps to take arbitrary text and create a date object

I have a simple `ui.Prompt()` that asks for a date in human-friendly terms, like "MM-DD-YYYY". I want to do date math on it, so ...

```js
  // result from ui.Prompt(), ie "03/01/2019" march 1st
  var mytextdate = result.getResponseText(); 
  //I want to do date math, so need a date object ...
  var year_num = +mytextdate.substring(6,10);
  var month_num = +mytextdate.substring(0,2);
  var day_num = +mytextdate.substring(3,5);
  var date_mytextdate = new date(year_num, month_num -1, day_num);
```

The script fails with 'date is undefined' at this point, before I can even do my date math. However I can retrieve the values for `year_num`, `month_num`, and `day_num` without a problem. What else do I need to make `date()' valid?

Comment: How about modifying from ``new date(`` to ``new Date(``? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: YES! This just reinforces to me how crap-tastic cAsE-SeNsItIvE scripting languages are! I had forgotten about that.

Answer (score 0):

Make you last line:

```
var date_mytextdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(year_num, month_num -1, day_num),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM-dd-yyyy");
```

- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)

Comment: Did you mean `Date` like JS Date constructor?